# How do I send data to the client when a process is done running on the server using socket io?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, backend

I have a long running process on the backend. When it is done:

1. broadcast it to all clients currently connections.
2. send it to a specific connected client.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Socket object has a property to send broadcast events:

   **io.on("connection", (socket) => {
   socket.broadcast.emit("hello", "world");
   });**

   You can see more on: [Broadcasting events](https://socket.io/docs/v3/broadcasting-events)

2. You can join the user into a room with the user id like this:

   **socket.join(userId);**

   and then emit an event doing something like this:

   **io.to(userId).emit('hello', "world");**